# Is a JSON value in double quote a valid JSON?

Tags: json, rest, api

Is the below value a valid JSON if its a string.

```
"{ "key":"value" }"
```

If yes , when building a rest api should the response Content-Type be application/JSON  or text/plain ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not valid JSON, because the double quotes within the string are not escaped.

This is valid JSON, it describes an object with a single property:

```
{ "key":"value" }
```

This is also valid JSON, it describes a string (which, as it happens, contains the JSON for an object):

```
"{ \"key\":\"value\" }"
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log(typeof JSON.parse(document.getElementById("obj").value));
console.log(typeof JSON.parse(document.getElementById("str").value));
```

```html
<!-- This is a convenient way to avoid the issue with escaping the backslash in a string or template literal, which would otherwise obscure the point... -->
<input type="hidden" id="obj" value='{ "key":"value" }'>
<input type="hidden" id="str" value='"{ \"key\":\"value\" }"'>
```

> when building a rest api should the response Content-Type be application/JSON or text/plain ?

It should be `application/json` (but I don't think capitalization matters).